# Insert row if query condition met JPA and spring

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb

I think this question is similar to [Data base pessimistic locks with Spring data JPA (Hibernate under the hood)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48116330/data-base-pessimistic-locks-with-spring-data-jpa-hibernate-under-the-hood) but thought I would ask separately as not exactly the same.

I have a multi threaded/node springboot application on top of a mariadb database with a table like

```
CREATE TABLE job (
id      INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
owner   VARCHAR(50),
status  VARCHAR(10) );
```

Have a `Job` domain class as you'd expect.

Have a `JobRepository` interface which extends `CrudRepository<Job,Integer>` and a service class.

The application rule is we cannot insert a new job if same owner and set of status values. e.g. If this was old school native sql I would just:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO job (owner, status)
SELECT 'fred', 'init' FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(   SELECT 1 FROM job
    WHERE owner = 'fred' AND status IN ('init', 'running')
);
COMMIT;
```

But how to I do this in JPA/CrudRepository.

I split into DB operations. Defined a repository method:

```
@Lock(LockModeType.READ)
long countByOwnerAndStatusIn(String owner, List<String> status);
```

And then had a service method like:

```
@Transactional
public Job createJob(Job job) {
    if (jobRepository.countByOwnerAndStatusIn(job.getOwner(), Job.PROGRESS_STATUS) == 0) {
        // Sleeps just to ensure conflicts
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        Job newJob = jobRepository.save(job);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        return newJob
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But with this I do not get the desired effect.

LockModeType of READ and WRITE allow duplicates to be created.

LockModeType of PESSIMISTIC_READ and PESSIMISTIC_WRITE can result in deadlock errors.

So I guess I am after one of two options:

- Is there a way to make get the `INSERT...SELECT WHERE NOT EXISTS`
  into a JPA/CrudRepository method?
- Is there a way to get the serivce
  method to effectively wrap the count check and the insert in the same
  lock?

If there is no way to do either I guess I'll try and get access to the underlying jdbc connection and explicity run a `LOCK TABLE` statement (or the insert...select, but I don't like the idea of that, keeping it JPA like is probably better).

Hope I have explained myself properly. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried just using a nativeQuery?

Comment: So you mean have a CrudRepository method with an insert statement in the `@query` annotation. Where I would pass the individual fields as parameters? Seems that would work according to other questions. But how to capture auto incremented id number?

Comment: @Sodved - Are you saying that JPA gets in the way of doing certain MySQL tasks?